# How to get an attribute to act as [Conditional("DEBUG")]?

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a C# program where some parts of code are generated using D-style mixins (i.e., the body of the method is compiled, executed, and results inserted into a class). The method is marked with `[MixinAttribute]` and, naturally, I don't want it to be compiled into the program. Is there some cheap way of preventing the method decorated with this attribute from being included in a build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is with compiler conditionals:

```
#if DEBUG
[MixinAttribute]
// method you don't want included
#endif
```

The problem with this approach is that you then create a member which will be unavailable in builds where DEBUG is not defined. You then have to mark all usages with the conditional, and I don't think this is what you want. It's not quite clear but I think what you are really asking is how you create dynamic call sites at build time, or, rather, at JIT time (which is what the `ConditionalAttribute` controls). If this is the case, you can't really do this easily in C# without using some kind of dynamic dispatch overriding (using some proxying library) or by using some post-processing tool like PostSharp to manipulate the compiler output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This sucks though :)